# How to use polars dataframes with scikit-learn?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, python-polars

I'm unable to use polars dataframes with scikitlearn for ML training.

Currently I'm doing all the dataframe preprocessing in polars and during model training i'm converting it into a pandas one in order for it to work.

Is there any method to directly use polars dataframe as it is for ML training without changing it to pandas?

Comment: Can you add a small example of what you want to achieve?

Comment: During fit and transform operations, sklearn is not accepting polars dataframes

Comment: You should make an example. See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You must call `to_numpy` when passing a `DataFrame` to sklearn. Though sometimes `sklearn` can work on polars `Series` it is still good type hygiene to transform to the type the host library expects.

```py
import polars as pl
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

data = pl.DataFrame(
    np.random.randn(100, 5)
)

x = data.select([
    pl.all().exclude("column_0"),
])

y = data.select(pl.col("column_0").alias("y"))


x_train = x[:80]
y_train = y[:80]

x_test = x[80:]
y_test = y[80:]


m = LinearRegression()

m.fit(X=x_train.to_numpy(), y=y_train.to_numpy())
m.predict(x_test.to_numpy())
```

Comment: Thank you. I just need one more thing during encoding of categorical features using sklearn's one hot encoding or any other techniques what should I do then. It is not getting encoded.

Comment: Also, if i convert x_train or x_test to multidimensional numpy arrays, then i want to know whether more memory is used or not (I mean some memory for polars dataframe + some memory for numpy array). If it occupies extra memory then it will be a problem na if my system has less ram.

Comment: This answer will be out of date when current development version 1.4 is released, and the functionality is available in the nightly wheels.  See my answer for links to relevant changelog entries and Github PRs.

Answer (score 5):

Since asking the question, scikit-learn 1.4 was released and is quite compatible with polars.

For example, see the [`set_output()`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.compose.ColumnTransformer.html#sklearn.compose.ColumnTransformer.set_output) method of an instance of the [`sklearn.compose.ColumnTransformer`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.compose.ColumnTransformer.html#sklearn-compose-columntransformer). It can be used as follows.

We start with some sample data

```py
import polars as pl

df = pl.DataFrame({
    "num": [1, 2, 3],
    "cat": ["a", "b", "c"],
})
```

and apply the `ColumnTransformer` as follows.

```py
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler, OrdinalEncoder
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer

# create column transformer
transformer = ColumnTransformer(
    transformers=[
        ("num", StandardScaler(), ["num"]),
        ("cat", OrdinalEncoder(), ["cat"]),
    ]
)

# enable polars output
transformer.set_output(transform="polars")

# fit and transform polars dataframe
transformer.fit_transform(df)
```

The output again is a [`pl.DataFrame`](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/dataframe/index.html) object.

```
shape: (3, 2)
┌───────────┬──────────┐
│ num__num  ┆ cat__cat │
│ ---       ┆ ---      │
│ f64       ┆ f64      │
╞═══════════╪══════════╡
│ -1.224745 ┆ 0.0      │
│ 0.0       ┆ 1.0      │
│ 1.224745  ┆ 2.0      │
└───────────┴──────────┘
```

Answer (score 1):

```
encoding_transformer1 = ColumnTransformer(
    [("Normalizer", Normalizer(), ['Age', 'Fare']),
     ("One-hot encoder",
      OneHotEncoder(dtype=int, handle_unknown='infrequent_if_exist'),
      ['Pclass', 'Sex', 'SibSp', 'Parch', 'Embarked'])],
    n_jobs=-1,
    verbose=True,
    verbose_feature_names_out=True)

encoding_transformer1.fit(xtrain)
train_data = encoding_transformer1.transform(xtrain).tocsr()
test_data = encoding_transformer1.transform(xtest).tocsr()
```

I'm getting this error:

```
ValueError: Specifying the columns using strings is only supported for pandas DataFrames
```

what should i do?

Comment: I found one hot encoding by to_dummies method, but how can we do other encoding methods.

Answer (score 1):

The upcoming development version of scikit-learn, 1.4, has [added](https://scikit-learn.org/dev/whats_new/v1.4.html#changes-impacting-all-modules) polars output support (and added support for `__dataframe__` protocol to Estimators). See the github PRs [26464](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/pull/26464) and [27315](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/pull/27315) for more info

(Note: I just happened across this question and then saw this in the scikit-learn changelog, credit goes to [Thomas J. Fan](https://github.com/thomasjpfan))

Edit: ColumnTransformer for preprocessing may (hopefully!) [be coming as well](https://github.com/scikit-learn/administrative/blob/master/meeting_notes/2023-11-27.md#topics), but is not yet available in the nightlies.